# Clear-Variable won't work in a function

Tags: function, powershell, csv

I suspect this is some implicit/explicit issue I don't fully understand. A lot of my scripts involve getting info from servers, populating variables with the data, and writing the variables to a CSV file. To that end, I've re-used a function called Write-CSV:

```
function Write-CSV {
$NewLine = "{0},{1},{2} -f $Server,$Data1,$Data2
$NewLine | Add-Content -Path $CSV
}
```

It seems to work well, except when one of the servers in my server list is offline. I report the event like so:

```
$Data1 = "Offline"; $Data2 = $Null; Write-CSV
```

What was happening that the `$Data1` value was getting retained for the next server's results. So, say, Server #5 in my list was offline. The CSV file would end up looking like this:

```
Server Data1 Data2
...
server4 datapoint1 datapoint2
server5 Offline 
server6 Offline datapoint2
server7 Offline datapoint2
```

To prevent that, I added the following line to the *end* of my Write-CSV function:

```
clv Data1,Data2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

`CLV` being an alias for `Clear-Variable`. My thought was that all the variables would be cleared out for when the next server in line was addressed. But the `$Data1` column still shows Offline for the entire rest of the list.

I tested the function calling each line separately in the ISE and the clv works. But in a script it fails. I ended up adding the clv line to the end of my `foreach ($server in $serverlist)` loop--meaning it's operating *outside* of the function. But I'd rather it be a part of the function itself for future scripts, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This just seems like a scope issue. What happens when you do this? `Clear-Variable Data1,Data2 -Scope 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Comment: FYI I made an edit to make CLV more clear. First time I read it I thought you were making a typo with CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just be using parameters for you functions and then you would not have to worry about this scope issue you are having.

For the variables `$Data1` and `$Data2` it is safe to assume they are declared in another scope. Using `Clear-Variable`s `-Scope` parameter might be all you need to do.

```
Clear-Variable Data1,Data2 -Scope 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

The `1` is a reference to the parent scope. If that is not where the variables were declared you could also use "Global". See [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849960.aspx) for more information

Comment: That did the trick, and I learned something new. Thanks, Matt.